# Superimpose widgets in Qt designer

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a Qt application and I would like to superimpose a button on a QTreeWidget using the layouts.
In fact, when I click on an item, I want the button to set visible, and centered above the tree. The button have to stay at the foreground until I click.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html ?

Comment: Not really, I want the button appears above the tree and takes the focus (as a modal pop-up). The problem with the stackWidget is that I can't see the 2 widgets in the same window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [QStackedLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html) and change it's [stacking mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html#stackingMode-prop) to `QStackedLayout::StackAll`, when you need to show both widgets. Methods would be something like this:

```
void Widget::showButton()
{
    stackedLayout->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);
    stackedLayout->setCurrentWidget(widgetWithButton);
}

void Widget::hideButton()
{
    stackedLayout->setCurrentWidget(treeWidget);
    stackedLayout->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackOne);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's exactly what I wanted