# Custom widget in Qt Designer with pre-existing layout in frame

Tags: c++, user-interface, widget, qt4, qt-creator

A project uses  custom frame widget that implements a kind of "cover" that hides widgets (think of it as of security cover that prevents pressing buttons).This is a required visual design. Qt version is 4.6

```
#ifndef CQFRAME_H
#define CQFRAME_H

#include <QFrame>

#include <QtDesigner/QDesignerExportWidget>

//! [0] //! [1]
class CQFrame : public QFrame   
// our agreement about "custom" widgets is to start them with CQ
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(FrameColorStyle)

    Q_PROPERTY(FrameColorStyle colorStyle READ getColorStyle WRITE setColorStyle)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool border READ border WRITE setBorder)
//! [0]
private:
    bool curCover;
    QFrame *frameCover;
public:
    enum FrameColorStyle  {fcDark, fcLight, fcTransparent, fcSystemDefault, fcRed, fcGreen, fcBlue};

    CQFrame(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void setCoverPropertie();
    void setCover(bool state);
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
    FrameColorStyle m_colorStyle;
    QString pstylebord;
    bool m_border;
//! [2]
};
//! [1] //! [2]

#endif
```

I omitted getters and setters that are irrelevant to the problem. Here is implementation:

```
void CQFrame::setCoverPropertie()
{
    QString str, strAlpha, gradient1, gradient2;
    strAlpha.setNum(200);
    gradient1 = "rgba("+str.setNum(cwDisableColor.red())+", "
                +str.setNum(cwDisableColor.green())
                +", "+str.setNum(cwDisableColor.blue())
                +" ," +strAlpha+ " )";
    gradient2 = "rgba("+str.setNum(cwLbColor.red())+", "
                +str.setNum(cwLbColor.green())+", "
                +str.setNum(cwLbColor.blue())+" ," +strAlpha+ " )";

    QStackedLayout *stackedLayout = new QStackedLayout(this);
    frameCover  = new QFrame(this);     
    frameCover->setGeometry(rect());
    frameCover->setStyleSheet("QFrame{border:5px solid  "+strLbColor+"; "
                                  "border-radius: 10px; background-color: "
                                  "qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0.5, stop: 0 "
                                  +gradient1+" , stop: 1 "+gradient2+"); }");

    stackedLayout->addWidget(frameCover);
    stackedLayout->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);
}

void CQFrame::setCover(bool state)
{
    frameCover->setVisible(curCover = state);
}

void CQFrame::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    if (curCover)
        frameCover->setGeometry(rect());
}
```

The design isn't mine, I was asked to fix strange visual glitches it experiences.  This "frame" is used in Qt designer as one of widgets. After a while suddenly everything resizes, which prompted question "what is wrong with this code". Qt  fires warning about attempt to add layout while one already exist: I suppose  *that* may cause a problem, because a frame must have only one layout at time? Code generated by Qt Creator looks something like

```
void setupUi(CQFrame *CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm)
    {
        if (CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm->objectName().isEmpty())
            CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm"));
        CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm->resize(735, 241);
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(CQWnd1T2SeparateONForm); // warning here
}
```

There is similar problem with standard QMainWindow which always got own "special" layout, which Qt Creator solves  automatically, by adding a central widget to the layout  and everything else is added to that widget. What I don't know that is how to simulate same behavior with a custom widget with Qt Creator plugin.
Or what alternative design for CQFrame can be used. CQFrame reused in dozen project, in about 30+ panels, so reuse of code for them all is a strict requirement.
Current plugin is very basic:

```
class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT CQFramePlugin : public QObject,
                             public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface)

public:
    CQFramePlugin(QObject *parent = 0);

    bool isContainer() const;
    bool isInitialized() const;
    QIcon icon() const;
    QString domXml() const;
    QString group() const;
    QString includeFile() const;
    QString name() const;
    QString toolTip() const;
    QString whatsThis() const;
    QWidget *createWidget(QWidget *parent);
    void initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *core);

private:
    bool initialized;
};
```

.cpp for it:

```
#include "cqframe.h"
#include "cqframeplugin.h"

#include <QtPlugin>

CQFramePlugin::CQFramePlugin(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    initialized = false;
}

void CQFramePlugin::initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface * /* core */)
{
    if (initialized)
        return;

    initialized = true;
}

bool CQFramePlugin::isInitialized() const
{
    return initialized;
}

QWidget *CQFramePlugin::createWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    return new CQFrame(parent);
}

QString CQFramePlugin::name() const
{
    return "CQFrame";
}

QString CQFramePlugin::group() const
{
    return "CustomWidgets";
}

QIcon CQFramePlugin::icon() const
{
    return QIcon(":/Resources/frame_icon.png");
}

QString CQFramePlugin::toolTip() const
{
    return "";
}

QString CQFramePlugin::whatsThis() const
{
    return "";
}

bool CQFramePlugin::isContainer() const
{
    return true;
}

QString CQFramePlugin::domXml() const
{
    return "<ui language=\"c++\">\n"
           " <widget class=\"CQFrame\" name=\"Frame\">\n"
           "  <property name=\"geometry\">\n"
            "   <rect>\n"
            "    <x>0</x>\n"
            "    <y>0</y>\n"
            "    <width>120</width>\n"
            "    <height>80</height>\n"
            "   </rect>\n"
            "  </property>\n"
           " </widget>\n"
           "</ui>";
}

QString CQFramePlugin::includeFile() const
{
    return "cqframe.h";
}
```

Comment: After all this time nobody has even posted a comment to this question... Looking through it, it just seems to be very incomplete. You should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example]http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am not that familiar with QT, but isn't there a memory leak here? `QStackedLayout *stackedLayout = new QStackedLayout(this);` creates a new object on the heap that never seems to be deleted. Also, a new object is created on every call.... And Shouldn't all widgets be added to this stack, including the one you wish to cover? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius That's the red herring of Qt, that describes general rule of how iwndows in existing GUIs work. If you destroy in  destructor, you'll get UB while executing   destructor of object class (QObject). Because base object of all classes destroys all  "owned" widgets. If widget is created with a widget as parameter of constructor, it is "owned".

Comment: Ok, I didn't know. But a QStackedLayout is not a QWidget... It's a QLayout (see my link). Will that also be deleted?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius  had to check that.. yes.. if it wasn't removed by setting up a new layout (and we are returning to the attempt to set a _second_ one). And I agree ,t hat the logic is dodgy.. yet is is how the pre-OOP widgets (or "windows", in case of Microsoft's GUI) are working on level of  OS implementation: if you destroy high-level window, all windows inside it are destroyed, same with hiding , etc. There is no OS analog of layout, it's an abstract class that represents algorithm that maintains positioning  of widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I haven't worked with QT yet, but I'm going to gie it a try. First thing, I think, is that you should use the `QStackedLayout` to cover the widgets ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717022/superimpose-widgets-in-qt-designer) and [QT manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html)). But you need to have a single stack.

So the stack should be a private member of CQFrame. E.g.

```
class CQFrame : public QFrame   
{
[...]
private:

    QWidget* _frame; // Frame to cover.
    QFrame* _frameCover;
    QStackedLayout* _stackedLayout;
[...]
```

And probably:

```
CQFrame::~CQFrame()
{
    delete _stackedLayout;
    delete _frameCover;
}
```

Then you could already initialize everything in the constructor

```
CQFrame::CQFrame(QWidget* parent = 0, QWidget* frame)
    : QFrame(parent)
    , _frame(frame)
    , _frameCover(new QFrame(this))
    , _stackedLayout(new QStackedLayout(this))
{
        _frameCover->setGeometry(rect());
        [...]
        _stackedLayout->addWidget(frame);
        _stackedLayout->addWidget(frameCover);
        //default:_stackedLayout->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackOne);
}
```

You could then switch between widgets in the stack using

```
void CQFrame::SetCover(bool state)
{
    if (state) _stackedLayout->setCurrentWidget(_frameCover);
    else _stackedLayout->setCurrentWidget(_frame);
}
```

Maybe this helps you.

**edit2:**
**I removed this code, as it was incorrect, both in coding format, as in idea**
So I checked the QT sources [QStackedLayout.cpp](http://search.cpan.org/~dongxu/Qt-Gui-0.01_05/lib/Qt/Gui/QStackedLayout.pm) and [QLayout](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/d7/d7b/qlayout_8cpp-source.html) and it seems a QWidget can have only one layout. If you add another layout, you get an error.
Furthermore, a QStackedLayout is a QLayout, is QObject. That could indicate it is automatically removed?

I'm not sure of the cover is implemented in QT as it should. It seems like you have a QWidget you want to cover, *on top of which* you put a QStackedLayout that is not used as designed i.e. switching stack objects, *on top of which* you put a *new* QWidget that is made visible or not.
And maybe that bottom QWidget is already in a (stacked)layout, etc.

Comment: that's all fine..except... you can't use safely this in initialization list, not at least in compilers we use.. And Qt's feature is that you never should delete widgets. it  will delete them  automatically, when deleting widget that owns them. In general only one widget _ever_ gets deleted, that's main window and may be some floating dialogs\panels \windows if they exist.

Comment: OK, I didn't know. That seems dodgy logic: it is very easy to accidentally create multiple objects doing the same thing. And how about the QStackedLayout? Is that also automatically destroyed?

Comment: And regarding the initialization: it's just a suggestion: you could just use `CQFrame::setCoverPropertie()`... or `CQFrame::setCoverProperty()` or `CQFrame::setCoverProperties()` if you correct the spelling. ;)

Comment: J.H.Bonarius probably..that name reminded me of "How to write unmaintainable code".. should have to  fix it in about 40 or so files, when I'll be at refactoring :P

Comment: Haha, I love that page! I wish I could help you with compiling code. Seems interesting to work with QT. But currently I'm using Matlab, Python, C# and visual C/C++, all on windows, so little use for QT. Of could I could try to install a VM of run this on my RPi (Rapbian/Pixel). But I would need a complete verifiable example.

Comment: i actually have to use qt on windows with visual c++, just same code goes to linux. I suppose you mean that you're using MFC

Comment: Somebody gave me a -1 for thinking along, while did not give a better answer himself...

Comment: happens... furthermore, QStackedLayout is the a weird layout that can't have layouts in itself, only widgets.. what those  dumbasses were doing they were inserting layout in designer, overriding it with QStackedLayout later, then inserting another layout..  widgets appear to be "hang" in same place" until some resizing happens. And they managed to repeat it in about 40-50 places for a year, _ignoring_ warning messages and bug until they decided to question it

Comment: Ironically, I can't beat out of devs that they would stop add two layouts to the frame.  Even using edit to your answer, there is language barrier  meeting stubbornness barrier "It's just a warning, it cannot be the reason". Seem Qt is absolutely OK with incorrect layout usage, instead it writes warning into qDebug() which no one ever reads.